# Is %p specifier only for valid pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, reinterpret-cast

Suppose on my platform `sizeof(int)==sizeof(void*)` and I have this code:

```
printf( "%p", rand() );
```

Will this be undefined behavior because of passing a value that is not a valid pointer in place of `%p`?

Comment: The standard does state *If a conversion speciﬁcation is invalid, the behavior is undeﬁned*.

Comment: I guess this boils down to a question of how special the pointers really are. I'm very curious to see a good answer.

Comment: "`p` The argument shall be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined manner." Well a `void*` can't be dereferenced anyway, so it doesn't have to be dereferenceable, but I'd think it's implementation defined.

Comment: Even if this was valid in thoery, it would still require a cast: `printf( "%p", reinterpret_cast<void*>(rand()) );`

Comment: @MSalters: you mean `printf("%p", (void *) rand());`. Notice the question is tagged as `C`.

Comment: @ninjalj The question has `c++` and `reinterpret-cast` tags? EDIT: just checked the question edit history. Sorry ninjalj, the tags were changed and then changed back.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To expand upon @larsman's answer (which says that since you violated a constraint, the behavior is undefined), here's an actual C implementation where `sizeof(int) == sizeof(void*)`, yet the code is not equivalent to `printf( "%p", (void*)rand() );`

The Motorola 68000 processor has 16 registers which are used for general computation, but they are not equivalent. Eight of them (named `a0` through `a7`) are used for accessing memory (address registers) and the other eight (`d0` through `d7`) are used for arithmetic (data registers). A valid calling convention for this architecture would be

1. Pass the first two integer parameters in `d0` and `d1`; pass the rest on the stack.
2. Pass the first two pointer parameters in `a0` and `a1`; pass the rest on the stack.
3. Pass all other types on the stack, regardless of size.
4. Parameters passed on the stack are pushed right-to-left regardless of type.
5. Stack-based parameters are aligned on 4-byte boundaries.

This is a perfectly legal calling convention, similar to calling conventions used by many modern processors.

For example, to call the function `void foo(int i, void *p)`, you would pass `i` in `d0` and `p` in `a0`.

Note that to call the function `void bar(void *p, int i)`, you would also pass `i` in `d0` and `p` in `a0`.

Under these rules, `printf("%p", rand())` would pass the format string in `a0` and the random number parameter in `d0`. On the other hand, `printf("%p", (void*)rand())` would pass the format string in `a0` and the random pointer parameter in `a1`.

The `va_list` structure would look like this:

```
struct va_list {
    int d0;
    int d1;
    int a0;
    int a1;
    char *stackParameters;
    int intsUsed;
    int pointersUsed;
};
```

The first four members are initialized with the corresponding entry values of the registers. The `stackParameters` points to the first stack-based parameters passed via the `...`, and the `intsUsed` and `pointersUsed` are initialized to the number of named parameters which are integers and pointers, respectively.

The `va_arg` macro is a compiler intrinsic which generates different code based on the expected parameter type.

- If the parameter type is a pointer, then `va_arg(ap, T)` expands to `(T*)get_pointer_arg(&ap)`.
- If the parameter type is an integer, then `va_arg(ap, T)` expands to `(T)get_integer_arg(&ap)`.
- If the parameter type is something else, then `va_arg(ap, T)` expands to `*(T*)get_other_arg(&ap, sizeof(T))`.

The `get_pointer_arg` function goes like this:

```
void *get_pointer_arg(va_list *ap)
{
    void *p;
    switch (ap->pointersUsed++) {
    case 0: p = ap->a0; break;
    case 1: p = ap->a1; break;
    case 2: p = *(void**)get_other_arg(ap, sizeof(p)); break;
    }
    return p;
}
```

The `get_integer_arg` function goes like this:

```
int get_integer_arg(va_list *ap)
{
    int i;
    switch (ap->intsUsed++) {
    case 0: i = ap->d0; break;
    case 1: i = ap->d1; break;
    case 2: i = *(int*)get_other_arg(ap, sizeof(i)); break;
    }
    return i;
}
```

And the `get_other_arg` function goes like this:

```
void *get_other_arg(va_list *ap, size_t size)
{
    void *p = ap->stackParameters;
    ap->stackParameters += ((size + 3) & ~3);
    return p;
}
```

As noted earlier, calling `printf("%p", rand())` would pass the format string in `a0` and the random integer in `d0`. But when the `printf` function executes, it will see the `%p` format and perform a `va_arg(ap, void*)`, which will use `get_pointer_arg` and read the parameter from `a1` instead of `d0`. Since `a1` was not initialized, it contains garbage. The random number you generated is ignored.

Taking the example further, if you had `printf("%p %i %s", rand(), 0, "hello");` this would be called as follows:

- `a0` = address of format string (first pointer parameter)
- `a1` = address of string `"hello"` (second pointer parameter)
- `d0` = random number (first integer parameter)
- `d1` = 0 (second integer parameter)

When the `printf` function executes, it reads the format string from `a0` as expected. When it sees the `%p` it will retrieve the pointer from `a1` and print it, so you get the address of the string `"hello"`.  Then it will see the `%i` and retrieve the parameter from `d0`, so it prints a random number. Finally, it sees the `%s` and retrieves the parameter from the stack. But you didn't pass any parameters on the stack! This will read undefined stack garbage, which will most likely crash your program when it tries to print it as if it were a string pointer.

Answer (score 13):

C standard, 7.21.6.1, The `fprintf` function, states just

> `p`  The argument shall be a pointer to `void`.

By Appendix J.2, this is a *constraint*, and violating a constraint causes UB.

(Below is my previous reasoning why this should be UB, which was too complicated.)

<del>That paragraph does not describe how the `void*` is retrieved from the `...`, but the only way that the C standard itself offers for this purpose is 7.16.1.1, The `va_arg` macro, which warns us that</del>

> <del>if *type* is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the default argument promotions), the behavior is undefined</del>

If you read 6.2.7, Compatible type and composite type, then there's no hint that `void*` and `int` should be compatible, regardless of their size. So, I'd say that since `va_arg` is the only way to implement `printf` *in standard C*, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Don't know where to look in the standard, but isn't storing a pointer in a large enough integer type and then storing it back again guaranteed to be safe? And as the integer type in discussion is not bigger than the pointer, converting the integer to a pointer should be safe, no?

Comment: @BoBTFish: 7.16.1.1 explicitly gives UB for non-compatible types, and "big enough" is not a sufficient condition for two types to be compatible. E.g, by 6.2.5, "`char` [shall] have the same range,
representation, and behavior as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`", but "[i]rrespective of the choice made, `char` is a separate type from the other two and is not compatible with either."

Comment: The language specification does not need to describe how the `void*` is retrieved from the `...`. The fact that you passed an `int` when the specification says "shall be a pointer to `void`" means that you violated a constraint and have triggered UB.

Comment: `va_args` aside, converting between integers and pointers *is* allowed. From my c11 final draft, `6.3.2.3.5`:"An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
result is implementation-defined..." ("previously specified" is null pointer constant). The type `intptr_t` is specifically provided as an integer type that *will* work correctly. Still doesn't answer the question about printing an invalid pointer though. But implementation defined is not undefined.

Comment: @RaymondChen: good point. Looked up the reference for that and shortened the answer.

Comment: @BoBTFish: yes, converting is allowed, but in a `...` there's no possibility for a conversion because the arguments don't have types to convert *to* until `va_arg` is called.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's undefined. From C++11, 3.7.4.2/4:

> The effect of using an invalid pointer value (including passing it to a deallocation function) is undefined.

with a footnote:

> On some implementations, it causes a system-generated runtime fault.

Comment: But what is "using" a pointer value? Doesn't that involve dereferencing?

Comment: @larsmans: No, deferenencing it is called "dereferencing", not "using". Using the value of an object means that it appears in an expression where an _rvalue_ is required; for example, as a function argument.

Answer (score -2):

%p is just a output format specification for printf. It doesn't need to dereference or validate the pointer in any way, although some compilers issue a warning if the type is not a pointer:

```
int main(void)
{
    int t = 5;
    printf("%p\n", t);
}
```

Compilation warning:

```
warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void*’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]
```

Outputs:

```
0x5
```

Comment: `%p` is also used to control how the type is extracted from the va_args at the other side. Exctracting from `va_args` wrongly is undefined behaviour.