# Can I output a Windows handle using %p specifier?

Tags: c++, winapi, pointers, handle, format-specifiers

This is a kind of follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11688162/57428). Windows SDK features `HANDLE` datatype that is defined in `WinNT.h` as follows:

```
typedef void *HANDLE;
```

This datatype is used to represent handles. Technically a handle is not a pointer - it's magic value that can only be used with Win32 functions. Yet it is declared to be represented with a datatype that is a `void*` typedef.

If I want to output the handle hex value with the following code:

```
HANDLE handle = ...;
printf("%p", handle);
```

will it be legal?

Comment: They're actually better documented than just that. As Raymond Chen [points out](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/21/358109.aspx), they're actually `DWORD*` but sometimes you set the low bit.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it's fine, for two reasons. Firstly it is actually a pointer (a pointer to void), and secondly %p doesn't magically check that the value on the stack is a pointer - it just grabs the next pointer-sized value and prints it out.

Comment: The second part is actually untrue, as the answers to the previous question show. E.g. Raymond Chen's example of the 68000, which grabs an `%p` argument from an address register, but `%u` from an integer register.

Comment: I didn't realise the Windows SDK was available for the 68000. On Windows at least, { int a = 0x12345678; printf("%p\n", a); } prints 12345678 just fine (in a 32 bit program of course).

Comment: Then have a look at the pecularties of the Xenon processor in the XBox 360. The x86 with its lack of registers is real the exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
HANDLE handle = ...;
printf("%p", handle);
```

Will this be legal? This would be correct because this will work. At the same time there is no "legal way" of printing handles. Microsoft is free to change the definition of handle to something different, like:

```
struct HANDLE { DWORD dummy; };
```

I even remember this definition was present in some older books.

32 bit NT has 2 types of handles: 32 bit and 64 bit. So, it is still necessary to check the handle that you have.